# Cloud Run requests triggers error 400 without reaching deployed service

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, fastapi, pydantic

I am currently using [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) to deploy an API and although everything was working fine I am now having quite a hard time understanding an error I get.

I created the API on python3 using [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com), the Location model is based on [Pydantic's](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/) BaseModel.

To illustrate it I have defined a test route as follow  :

```py
class Location(BaseModel):
    lat: float
    lng: float


@router.get('/test_404')
async def test_404(origin: Location = Body(...),
                   destination: Location = Body(...)):
    print(origin)
    print(destination)
    return {'res': 'ok'}
```

The route should take two arguments in the request's body : origin and destination, and it ***does*** but only when I deploy it locally.
This :

```py
url_local = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/test_404"
data = {
    'origin': {'lat': 104, 'lng': 342},
    'destination': {'lat': 104, 'lng': 342}
}
resp = requests.get(url_local, json = data)
print(resp.text)
```

Outputs :

```py
'{"res":"ok"}'
```

The issue arises when I deploy the same service on Cloud Run. All of my other routes work fine but here is the output I get when I use the code above with the container url :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>\n
    <html lang=en>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    \n
    <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    \n <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>\n
    \n <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n
    <p><b>400.</b>
        <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
        \n
    <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.
        <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

This is an error triggered by google and that does not let my request reach the service (no log entry)

I've searched online but did not find what causes this error. What am I missing ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373657/app-engine-400-your-client-has-issued-a-malformed-or-illegal-request/3375122) post, where a user experiences a similar message. After some reading, and seeing your example, I think the solution lies in the REST best [practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).

Strictly speaking, a GET request should not send any data when doing the request, other than anything incorporated within the URI. Technically, everything is possible, but you should use query parameters instead of sending a body.

Some API wrappers (like Cloud Run), may not accept this behaviour, while in your local test it may seem to work. Other API wrappers may just accept a body with a GET request. I would recommend sticking to the REST best practices and you are fine.

Comment: I thought so hard that google did something weird that I did not even take a look at what I what I was doing and it made sense. Thank you very much !