# How to hosting a WebSocket server in the Google Cloud Run

Tags: websocket, google-cloud-run

I would like to use Python-socketio and Flask to listen to a GCP Pub/Sub topic, retrieve the message, and send it to a React app. Here is the WebSocket server in Python:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import base64
import json
import humps
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", cors_allowed_methods="*")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def receive_pubsub_message():
    publish_message = request.get_json()

    if "message" in publish_message and "data" in publish_message["message"]:
        # Decode Pub/Sub message
        message_data = base64.b64decode(publish_message["message"]["data"]).decode("utf-8")
        request_json = humps.decamelize(json.loads(message_data))
    else:
        # Handle regular JSON payload (if necessary)
        request_json = humps.decamelize(request.get_json())
    print("request: ", request_json)
    
    # Emit the decoded message to all connected clients
    socketio.emit('new_message', request_json)
    print("Emitting new_message event to clients: ", request_json)

    # Acknowledge the Pub/Sub message by returning a 200 response
    return jsonify({}), 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8081)))
```

And here is the simple WebSocket client in React:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    // const socket = io("http://localhost:8081");

    const socket = io(
      "wss://xxx-uc.a.run.app"
    );

    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Connected to server: ", { socket });
    });

    // Listen for incoming messages
    socket.on("new_message", (msg) => {
      console.log("new message: ", { msg });
      // Use the callback function form of setMessages to ensure state updates properly
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, JSON.stringify(msg)]);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []); // Empty dependency array to run once on component mount

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Chat Application</h1>
      <div className="message-list">
        {messages.map((msg, idx) => (
          <div className="message" key={idx}>
            {msg}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This works well locally. However, when I deploy the server to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Cloud Run, I encounter the following error during polling:

https://xxx-uc.a.run.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Oiwn41V&sid=KenZXFDBdawUL3opAAAA 400

I checked the socket object when I initially start the client, and it appears to be connected. However, when I start sending messages to the PubSub topic, the client-side encounters a 400 error. Can anyone help me identify what I did wrong?

Comment: As per [this document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets)  ***WebSockets requests could still potentially end up at different instances, due to built-in load balancing.*** I believe this could be the reason. Also check for error code in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/core_errors#BAD_REQUEST).  and 

check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64336402/18265570)