# 400 Bad Request Request Header Or Cookie Too Large

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, web, server

We sometimes face
**'400 Bad Request
Request Header Or Cookie Too Large'** issue on our website.
Our app is built-in **PHP Laravel framework** and the server is the **google app engine standard environment**. Please let me know the right solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [400 Bad Request - request header or cookie too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524396/400-bad-request-request-header-or-cookie-too-large)

Comment: @nice_dev I don't have nginx.confg file on app engine standard environment.

Comment: Does this help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373657/app-engine-400-your-client-has-issued-a-malformed-or-illegal-request

Comment: Would you kindly provide an [mre] so we can see what may be causing it?